# 'reversed' node refs?

Tags: views

Here is the current situation:
i have an artist database and users can 'like' the artist with a flag button and that works great, but i need to use the 'like' data to get some other info

Case:
1. user likes artist(flag!)
2. user logs out
3. user returns to website and logs in and gets redirected to custom page

### 4. The custom page needs to contain nodes that reffer to the artist.

Its step 4 where i got stuck, i just don't know how to display the information from B to A in a view?

Using Drupal 6 and views 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In views edit > Relationships > add **Flags: User's flagged content** (also select Include only users who have flagged content.)

Comment: I did fixed it, but the solution above is not the thing i needed... i had to install a node refference module and include a other relationship.. still thanks :)